# 80s(?) short story about friendly koala-looking aliens

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Years ago, 40? my students had in their 8th grade reader a short story about a friendly alien who looked like a koala and so 'fit in' on Earth.  Alien befriended an Earthlings and they shared about their various 'cultures'.

I thought it was by Ray Bradbury or maybe Isaac Asimov.

Comment: Kind of makes me think of the Hoka stories,,,

Comment: @Shreedhar This needed a better title and wasn’t tagged correctly as two basic things to do in review. Please pay more attention in the First Posts queue.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a possibility I found, by searching Google books for the terms Spaceship + Koala.

It gave a few very brief snippets that made it seem like a possibility. THen a Google search found this article.

[The Star Dummy - Anthony Boucher (1952)](https://tthread.wordpress.com/2011/12/02/60/)

> Paul Peters is a small-time ventriloquist ...
>
> Seeking relaxation, Paul takes himself off to the zoo. Sadly,
> relaxation was not to be had that day as the zoo is atwitter. It seems
> there’s a strange beast in one of the cages, described simply as “like
> a koala, except where it’s like an anteater.” Ever intrigued, Paul
> makes his way to the scene of the mystery and finds a small furry
> creature not entirely unlike a koala drawing diagrams of the solar
> system in the dirt. ...
>
> Paul convinces the zoo staff that the whole thing is just one big
> publicity stunt. The two exit the zoo ...
>
> Mr. Koala isn’t here to harvest the world’s supply of eucalyptus
> leaves, but merely searching for his girlfriend who was lost on the
> planet a few weeks before ...  the two decide to form a ventriloquism
> act, get themselves on television and thus publicize themselves so
> that Ms. Koala can find them ...
>
> Not bad for a story, that interestingly, is all of 12 pages long.

Comment: You can read the whole story here https://archive.org/details/Fantastic_v01n02_1952-Fall_Missing_ibcbc_LSilver_dongev/page/n45/mode/2up

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for - thanks so much - there is a passage toward the end of the story (as the characters depart) that is a beautiful parallel to the Lord's Prayer "Our Father" in Matthew 6.  I have been looking for this for years.